# Will my Duplicator i3 be able to print this hole in the vertical wall without infill?

Tags: pla, print-quality, infill

Will my Duplicator i3 be able to print this hole in the vertical wall without infill?
The wall is 7mm the diameter of the hole is 24mm, the shell thickness is 0.8mm.

[image: Image of vertical wall with hole]

Comment: Hi @AndyAndy Welcome to the group. Unfortuantly this site is not the best at questions like this asking for an opinion. We prefer to see more solid questions such as at what kinds of prints are we able to print without infill. Or what are ways we can reduce the material needed for pints such as this one. Also the answer is yes, if you use a lot of outer shells.. Specifically on the top layers..

Comment: What do you mean by a lot of outer shells?

Comment: Is your question what is a shell, or what I mean by many? https://3dprintingforbeginners.com/glossary/shell-2/

Shell
Also know as outline or outer perimeter, the shell represents the outer wall of a 3D print.

Used in plural (“shells“) in conjunction with a number to describe the maximum thickness given to the outer wall. Printing with 4 shells means that your objects’ outer wall will be 4 times your 3D printer nozzle’s diameter (i.e 4 X 0,4mm = 1,6mm outer wall).

Comment: Do you really mean infil, or are you asking about support structure to handle bridging at the top of the hole?  And why not lay the part flat & print that way?

Comment: @StarWind I think this is a reasonable question, and it isn't opinion-based at all. Whether an object is printable can be established simply by trying to print it, or a more experienced 3D printer operator might be able to tell off-hand. It would be a good idea to add the settings used (the dimensions of the hole have since been added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. However I notice that some knowledge is missing due your comments.

The walls of the part is formed by 1 or several lines, this lines are called shell.

The Infill is the part that fills all within the walls or shell; you can set the infill by 5% to 100% depending in how strong you need the printed part or set 0 to get an empty shell.

The printer can be able to print any part, but some areas will need **supports**, this suports is a kind of outerfill to support areas that could overhang basically walls with 45 degrees or less, this support can be easily removed from the final part